# I need to get an alert of internet

Tags: validation

I am preparing the project 
When I am in the Web page and if suddenly lost my internet then it should show me an alert that your connection is how to do this

Answer (score 0):

as my understanding, the simplest solution is Ping-Pong every second, for example:

```
function testInternet()
{
    $.get(window.location.href, function() { 
     Console.write("success");
    })
    .done(function() {
       //alert( "second success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "Internet Error!!!!!!" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        //alert( "finished" );
     });
 }

 setInterval(testInternet, 1000);
```

Comment: its working when i  enter into the inspect element and turn off to offline but when i turn of my wifi its not showing any result